# Save and and post a matplotlib figure from user input while Flask application is live

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am running a Python Flask application deployed using Google Cloud Platform and am newer to web development.

My app takes in user input from a form (x and y coordinates), uses this input to create a plot using matplotlib, saves this plot as static/myplot.png, then posts this plot.

As you can probably tell, my app works fine LOCALLY but when deployed it cannot save the image to the static folder and pull from the static folder while live.

**form that takes in x and y from user**

```
{%  extends "preplot.html" %}

{%block xform%}
<form action = '/plot#bottom' method = 'post'>
<input type = 'number' name = 'xcord' id = 'x'/>
{%endblock xform%}

{%block yform%} 
<input type = 'number' name = 'ycord' id = 'y'/>
{%endblock yform%}

{%block cordsubmit%} 
<input type = 'submit' value = 'submit'/>
</form>
{%endblock cordsubmit%}
```

**main.py**: puts x and y into function to create plot, save's plot as static/myplot.png

```
@app.route("/plot", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def plot():
    form_data = request.form
    xcord = request.form.get('xcord')
    ycord = request.form.get('ycord')
    xcord = int(xcord)
    ycord = int(ycord)
    goal = Goal(xcord, ycord)
    percent = goal.is_goal()
    fig = goal.shot_chart()
    fig.savefig('static/myplot.png',  pad_inches=0, dpi=300)

    return render_template("plot.html", title = 'plot', fig = fig, form_data = form_data, xcord=xcord, ycord=ycord, percent=percent
```

**plot.html**: uses saved static/myplot.png to allow user to see their plot

```
<img src= "static/myplot.png" class = "soccer" height="504" width="864">
    <table class="center">
```